# How to name localized "Files" for binding in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a file localized for some languages. I mean `Countries_fr.xml`, `Countries_en.xml`, `Countries_de.xml` and so on.

I want each culture load its own file, when I do something like this:

```
App.ViewModel.LoadData(MyApp.Resources.AppResources.Countries);
```

(Is this correct?)

Then if the user's culture is french the french file get loaded.

My Question is: what should the name of these files be? is there an specific pattern?

And what is the way of adding these files, should I add them directly to `References` folder in designer or I should Open `AppResources.resx` and add these as a file to it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add localization files manually. Just go to your project properties and tick the languages you want to support in your app. Visual Studio will automatically add the resource files for the languages you chose under the Resources folder.